# External image in UserControl not loading when control is used

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, user-controls

I have an `Image` that I need to load from an external file into a `Button`.
The `Image` resides in a folder in the same directory as the final executable file.

```
/Resources/image.png
```

It's not included in the `Project Resources` and it should not be for the needs of the `Application`.
The `Image` is loaded and displayed into a `UserControl` fine, but when I place my `UserControl` into my main `View`,
I get the following error:

```
Cannot locate resource 'views/usercontrols/resources/playerbuttonsicons/repeat-icon.png'.
```

The `UserControl` is located under `Views/UserControls` in my `Project Tree` as the error says.
I have tried various ways of specifying the image path (absolute, relative, `uri`, `pack` etc), but none of them worked.
The problem is to be tackled using `xaml` only, if possible.

---

**UserControl code:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MusicPlayer.Views.UserControls.NowPlayingControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.Views.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignWidth="400"
             x:Name="ParentControl">

    <!--Resources-->
    <UserControl.Resources>  
    
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <!--Design-->
    <DockPanel x:Name="ParentContainer">
         <Button x:Name="btnPlay">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/PlayerButtonsIcons/play-icon.png" />
                </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

---

**MainView code:**

```
<Window x:Class="MusicPlayer.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.ViewModels"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.Views.UserControls"
        x:Name="ParentControl">

    <!--Resources-->
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="VM" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <!--Design-->
    <Grid x:Name="ParentContainer"
                  DataContext="{StaticResource VM}">  
        <uc:NowPlayingControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: In case the image file is an assembly resource in the assembly of the UserControl, set its Build Action to Resource, and load it by a full Pack URI like `MusicPlayer.Views.UserControls;component/Resources/PlayerButtonsIcons/play-icon.png` or `pack://application:,,,/MusicPlayer.Views.UserControls;component/Resources/PlayerButtonsIcons/play-icon.png`

Comment: Embedding the image in the assembly Resources is the final resolution. The file must reside in an external relative folder, so the it may be replaced without editing the application.

Comment: Then try `pack://siteoforigin:,,,/<AssemblyName>;component/Resources/PlayerButtonsIcons/play-icon.png`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf

Comment: `siteoforigin` gives me the following error: `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\MusicPlayer;component\Resources\PlayerButtonsIcons\play-icon.png'.`  Why does it reference the Visual Studio directory instead of the project?

Comment: No idea. Anyway, a relative path like `./Resources/PlayerButtonsIcons/play-icon.png` should of course work, as long as you make sure that it is actually valid, i.e. that such a path is valid relative to the current working directory of the application.

Comment: The path works fine when editing the `UserControl.xaml`. The image is displayed properly. When I am changing to `MainView.xaml` and try loading the `UserControl`, magic happens and I get the error. I think it has to do with relative paths on each `xaml` file, but my knowledge goes as far as this...

Comment: If the file is part of the project, set its Build Action to *Content*, and *Copy to Output Directory* to something else than *Do not copy*.

Comment: No, the files are not part of the project. They just reside in the output folder, so anyone can change them without having to rebuild the project.

Comment: That would be possible with a Content file. However, as said, make sure the path is valid relative to the current working directory of the application.

Comment: I included them into my `Resources` as `Content`, `Copy Always`. The error remains, but for some reason the debugging ignores the error and runs. Weird...

Comment: try  <Image Source="..\Resources/PlayerButtonsIcons/play-icon.png" />

Comment: Please see answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with the following steps.

1. Included all the external files into my `Project Resources`. Marked them as `Content` and `Copy Always`.
2. Instead of loading the `Images` into my `UserControl` at run-time, I loaded them in my `App.xaml` `Resources`.
3. The `Images` are now used as `StaticResource` in my `UserControl`.

---

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="MusicPlayer.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer"
             xmlns:ex="clr-namespace:SharpUtilities.WPF"
             StartupUri="Views/MainView.xaml">
    
    <Application.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="PlayerPlayIcon"
                     UriSource="Resources/play-icon.png" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

**UserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MusicPlayer.Views.UserControls.NowPlayingControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.Views.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignWidth="400"
             x:Name="ParentControl">

    <DockPanel x:Name="ParentContainer">
         <Button x:Name="btnPlay">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource PlayerPlayIcon}" />
                </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```